# Cannot install CAL License in Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, rds, cal

I am trying to install a RDS CAL license into a server and I am getting an error saying the license is already in use.

I already tried 2 different licenses, both of them should be clean and without any uses, so I am guessing I am failing something with this configuration.

This is the first time I am attempting to install such a license, so I might be missing something quite simple...

This is what I see in the diagnoser:

[image]

And this is what I see when I try to install the license:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems self explanatory. Microsoft has a licensing service center for this: (866) 230-0560 https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/Help/Contact.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: @GregAskew I understand your point. Nonetheless, I am not sure if this is a licensing issue per se, or if this is an error configuring the license on my side. Hence, I assumed posting this in ServerFault might get me some insight from someone else who might have faced a similar situation in the past.

Comment: If you are attempting to activate a CAL and Microsoft reports that a CAL has already been activated, only they can help you. Also, even if you did have a valid CAL, the system will not  function properly until you fix the remaining two problems (the server is not activated, and the licensing mode is not configured).